# написание строки из массива double[] array

Tags: java, массивы, double

Имеется массив дробных чисел.
{100.35, 200.46, 300.1, 400.89}
требуется написать метод, который преобразует массив в строку, который перечисляет все элементы массива через запятую. При этом необходимо, чтобы форматирование было с двумя знаками после запятой. Написал код следующего характера. Просьба сильно не смеяться, т.к. я только начал учить джаву.

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
if (array.length != 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        stringBuffer.append(df.format(array[i]) + ",");
    }
    stringBuffer.deleteCharAt(stringBuffer.lastIndexOf(","));
}
return stringBuffer.toString();
```

но вот вместо "100.35, 200.46, 300.10, 400.89" - мне выдается строка: "100.35, 200.46, 300.1, 400.89".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Test {

    private final static DecimalFormat FORMATER = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double [] array = {100.35, 200.46, 300.1, 400.89}; 
        System.out.println(arrayToString(array));
    }

    private static String arrayToString(final Double[] array) {        
        return Arrays.stream(array)
                .map(d -> FORMATER.format(d))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }
}
```

Comment: ошибка стало быть в том, что надо было формат указывать #.00?

Comment: да, 0 - показывает все цифры маски (включая 0), а # скрывает 0. кроме того , как по мне, в этом случае функциональный подход лучше. читается проще, кода меньше.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `0` (показывает начальные/конечные нули) вместо `#` (скрывает их) в форматной маске.

```java
double d = 100.10;
String fMask = "###.##";
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(fMask);
System.out.println(d + "(" + fMask + "): " + df.format(d));
fMask = "###.00";
df = new DecimalFormat(fMask);
System.out.println(d + "(" + fMask + "): " + df.format(d));
d = 0.10;
System.out.println(d + "(" + fMask + "): " + df.format(d));
fMask = "##0.00";
df = new DecimalFormat(fMask);
System.out.println(d + "(" + fMask + "): " + df.format(d));
```